# How are trapdoor functions developed/found and where can I find existing ones?

Tags: public-key, rsa, prime-numbers

Trapdoor functions are a fundamental part of public key cryptography. An example of the most common trapdoor is

- Prime Factorization, used in cryptosystems such as RSA

How are these trapdoor functions found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some theoretical constructions of TDP and you can find two examples in the [technical report by Oded Goldreich](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2011/159/). It is concerned with enhancements of trapdoor permutations, why they are required and two constructions of the enhanced TDP (in appendix) based on RSA and Rabin's collection.